# Не показывает введеноe имя с UIAlertController в UITableViewController? Решил таким образом:

Tags: objective-c

Вот пример кода:

```
#import "OMNoteTextViewController.h"

@interface OMNoteTextViewController ()

@end

@implementation OMNoteTextViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

if (self.note) {

    [self.textView setText:[self.note valueForKey:@"text"]];

}
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

[self setupAlert];
}

- (void)setupAlert {

self.alert =
[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Press save" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *actionSave = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"save" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

// Create a new note
    NSManagedObject *newNote = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newNote setValue:self.textView.text forKey:@"text"];
    [newNote setValue:self.alert.textFields[0].text forKey:@"name"];

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}];

[_alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {

    textField.placeholder = @"Enter name note";

}];

[self.alert addAction:actionSave];
```

}

```
- (IBAction)save:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

if (self.note) {
    // Update existing note
    [self.note setValue:self.textView.text forKey:@"text"];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];        
} else {        
    UIViewController *top = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    [top presentViewController:self.alert animated:YES completion:^{            
    }];
}  

}

@end
```

Comment: Перенес добавления нового объекта в UIAlertAction.